# How to save value in ComboBox after refreshing the Rally Dashboard

Tags: combobox, rally

So my question pertains to the ComboBox value for a custom app I created.

I've got the app on my Rally Dashboard, but I noticed that for other in-house Rally apps, if I choose a particular ComboBox value to filter on and then refresh the page, the last used filter is still applied to the data.

Is there a way that I can mimic this behavior for my custom app? Currently it follows the default behavior in selecting the first value possible.

(note: I know I can use the 'value' property to set a default value but I would like to know how to make it so that it saves/responds to what the user selects even on a page reload).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

All the best,
Masterme2

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using SDK 2.0 this is totally supported.  Check out the guide here on maintaining state: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/state

Basically you just need to configure your combobox to be stateful.  Here is an example making a combobox of defect priorities stateful:

```
this.add({
    xtype: 'rallyfieldvaluecombobox',
    model: 'Defect',
    field: 'Priority',
    stateful: true,
    stateId: this.getContext().getScopedStateId('priority')
});
```

The relevant properties are `stateful` and `stateId`.

Comment: Thanks for the timely response, Kyle! That worked when I deployed the app externally on my browser, but I still run into issues when pasting the src code into a Custom HTML app onto my dashboard and refresh the page. The state is not saved for that scenario. Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Comment: I just tried the code above on rally1 and it worked for me.  Are you sure you are using version 2.0?  2.0rc3 and below do not support state (although it does happen to work externally for the combobox, but that's the only situation in which it works)

Comment: I am indeed using sdk version 2.0. Strangely enough, on the actual Rally platform it is wickedly inconsistent. On some page refreshes I will have the saved state, but other times it will still just have the default first value... not quite sure what could be the issue here, but it's not too troublesome to deal with anyway- thanks for your help!